# Export data table to excel sheet with number format

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export-to-excel

I need to export a data set:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("tabless");
ds.Tables.Add(table01);
ds.Tables.Add(table02);
ds.Tables.Add(table03);
```

it contains 3 data table, each one of them is:

```
table01.Columns.Add("Branch",typeof(string));
table01.Columns.Add("Today", typeof(double));
table01.Columns.Add("MTD",typeof(double));
table01.Columns.Add("LM",typeof(double));
table01.Columns.Add("Differ",typeof(double),"LM-MTD");
table01.Columns.Add("YTD",typeof(double));
```

So I need to export them to an excel sheet with number format and comma separator.
Like when value = -200000 will be (200,000) with red color and value 300000 will be 300,000 and apply this to each table in the work sheet.
For more info check the below photo:

[Screenshot http://postimg.org/image/lj55lz6ib/](http://postimg.org/image/lj55lz6ib/)

Comment: How are you exporting to Excel now?

Comment: You could possibly use a Framework like ClosedXML or EPPlus

Comment: @T.Glatzer how to use it can give me an example .. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NumberingFormat

```
        //Create a NumberingFormat 
        NumberingFormat numForm2decim = new NumberingFormat();
        numForm2decim.NumberFormatId = 1u;
        numForm2decim.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("0.00");  

        //Use it in a CellFormat
        CellFormat cellformatNumber2Decim = new CellFormat();            
        cellformatNumber2Decim.NumberFormatId = numForm2decim.NumberFormatId;
        cellformatNumber2Decim.ApplyNumberFormat = true;

        //And apply the cellFormat to your Cell throw the StyleIndex Property
```

Comment: First Tchadizman .. thanks :)
and how to export to excel sheet ??

Comment: You must first create the excel docuement. Use the Create methode of SpreadsheetDocument
More info on :
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562522(v=office.14).aspx  or
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx